# There was no EndPoint listening at http://localhost/Service1.svc

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7.1

There was no endpoint listening at **http://localhost:6272/Service1.svc** that could accept the message. 
This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, 
if present, for more details.

**InnerException**  The remote server returned an error: NotFound

I have 2 solution projects

1.**MyApp**(Windows Application)

2.**WcfService1**(Class library)

My **Web.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

 <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
 </system.web>

<system.serviceModel>

<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:6272/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
    name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
      openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
      allowCookies="true" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
      messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
      useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>

 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
 </system.webServer>

 </configuration>
```

In my Service1.svc.cs I just returning **CookiesContainer** Object to **client(MyApp)**.

What should I do? Is there any change in my **web.config** file?

Comment: is your service hosted ?
from IE you can visit http://localhost:6272/Service1.svc and check if the service is running correctly.

Comment: yes. I host my service. these all works fine. But I didn't know why this error occure

Answer (score 0):

Your WcfService1 needs to be more than just a class library: you need to host the service somehow. There are a number of options, including using IIS and Self-Hosting. This is a little dated, but gives a good outline: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx